# How to make a Trigger to discount stock of ingredients from a product they order.?

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want to guide me how I can make a trigger that allows me to update the stock of ingredients that make up a product, based on the recipe that contains it.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockIngredients AFTER INSERT ON detail_orders
 FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE ingredient_id INT;
    DECLARE quantity DECIMAL;

    SELECT recp.ingredient_id, recp.quantity INTO ingredient_id, quantity
    FROM detail_orders deor, recipes recp 
    WHERE deor.food_id=NEW.food_id //5
    AND recp.food_id = deor.food_id;

    UPDATE ingredients SET stock_per_measure = stock_per_measure - quantity
    WHERE ingredients.id = ingredient_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

my error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1172 Result consisted of more than one row (SQL: insert into detail_orders (order_id, comment, food_id, quantity, price, updated_at, created_at) values (47, ?, 1, 1, 5000.00, 2020-04-09 22:00:12, 2020-04-09 22:00:12))"

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_number` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `board_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `detail_orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `food_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `combo_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `foods` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `recipes` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `ingredient_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `food_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `ingredients` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sale_price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `stock_per_measure` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `packing` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `measure` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity_per_measure` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `category_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

query

```
SELECT foods.name, 
       recipes.quantity as recipe_quantity,
       recipes.ingredient_id as recipe_ingredient,
       ingredients.name as ingredient_name,
       ingredients.stock_per_measure as ingredient_stock 
FROM foods, recipes,ingredients
WHERE foods.id =1
AND foods.id = recipes.food_id
AND ingredients.id = recipes.ingredient_id
```

result

```
name   | recipe_quantity| recipe_ingredient|ingredient_name|ingredient_stock
Burger |2               |1                 |bread          |180
Burger |1               |2                 |letucce        |2000
Burger |1               |3                 |tomato         |2000
Burger |100             |4                 |meat           |2000
```

Comment: Please add some data.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry, 
I am making an app for a restaurant and the client tells me that when ordering a product, the stock can be discounted from the ingredients, the product / food has a recipe this in order to reduce the stock of ingredients that are in stock

Comment: @nbk, 
the order table has an order detail, and order detail stores the product / food id and the food table is related to the recipe table, and said recipe is related to the ingredients table where ingredients has a stock name column

Comment: Your code hasn' any errors, but it should be obviuous, that i can only test something and reproduce a problem or even improve the trigger,. when i haven't any create tablesw and data in it, so that i can insert a new row in orders and see what the triger does.

Comment: @nbk, this is my error: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1172 Result consisted of more than one row (SQL: insert into `detail_orders` (`order_id`, `comment`, `food_id`, `quantity`, `price`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (47, ?, 1, 1, 5000.00, 2020-04-09 22:00:12, 2020-04-09 22:00:12))"

Comment: A recipe has more than one ingredient so that you can put it into variables.you have to join the order in the update clause and use the data.

Comment: please have alook at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and  check my answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/264810/190821  so can somepne test a trigger

Comment: @nbk, 
sorry but I don't understand why I should put the order id, I also put part of the MER

Comment: As you wont present data,  Your select returns multiple rows. This ca not be put into variables., so the selct doesn't work You now have TO make UPDATE ingredients innee rjoin orders inner join  recipes  Now you have in 1 row all data you need to update. That looks comlicated, but please i gave you plenyt opportunity to add data to your question

Comment: @nbk,  in this case it is better to make a cursor?

Comment: Like you wish it is possible with a cursor or an Update with inner joins, what ever suits you best, but if you get in troubloeyou still have to provide data like i shiwed you in dba.stackexchange.com/a/264810/190821

Comment: @nbk, problem solved